# Two device handy box (683)

Tags: electrical

I have a raco double two device gang box in one of my rooms. I found that a couple of those holes are stripped. Is it better to trying to tap it at 6/32 again, go to the next size which is 8/32 (tremendous difficulty finding 8/32 screws that are painted white or maybe i have to paint them) Or replace the box? What[image: two device handy box] would you suggest?

Comment: Different issue- talking about the double 6/32 to hold the receptacles holes for a handy double device box are stripped versus a double garage metal gang box itself to hold the cover were stripped. This is a double device handy box and need to know if it is permissible to tap those holes? How can that possibly be the same. Inspectors might not see this part but if either the plastic cover or the box itself is changed from 6/32 to 8/32 that could be a problem for some inspectors as told by raco. Any time you change hole sizes it could be a violation should be your argument. .different issue!

Answer (score 1):

I'm kind of confused as to why the box does not have a plaster ring on the box. Generally we used to retap to an 8/32 since the 6/32 is stirpped I don't think you would be able to retap. Probably wouldn't hurt to try. You can order trim screws with painted heads but you would probably have to order from an electrical wholesaler or a specialist like Fastenal and you probably would have to order a bulk amount. Last ditch if you can find a #8 or #10 metal screw with a trim painted head we have used them from time to time. I would cut off the point before installing so it wouldn't puncture the insulation of any wire.

Comment: Thank you fir your help. Code in cook county unless it changed recently which im going to check is that everything has to be emt conduit and metal boxes. Also thanks about a place to buy these screws.

Comment: I spoke to the inspector of our village..  no plastic period--only metal.